# Split object key/value pairs into separate objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I was wondering is there a way to split key/value pairs of objects and insert them into array so that I get array of objects.

Here is the code:

```js
let grades = [5,5,6,7,6,7,9,10,8,6]

let gradesSpread = {
   5:0,
   6:0,
   7:0,
   8:0,
   9:0,
   10:0
}


// This populates spreadGrades object as intended
for( let [index,grade] in grades.entries() ) {
   gradesSpread[grade]++
}
```

So now I want to get key/value pair from `gradesSpread` and create object for each and push it into new array.

I know I can use `Object.values()` and `Object.keys()` to get keys or values from object but I have no clue how I would go about adding those key value pairs into array of objects

For better visualization I need array to look something like this :

```
let finalSpread = [{5:0},{6:4}...]
```

I am open to all solutions also bonus points for making it so it does not need initialized object.

Comment: Where's that 4 coming form?: `{6:4}...]`

Comment: It is an example, not a reflection of data in the question.

Comment: How is grades array being used?

Comment: @zer00ne I made a fix it was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a).

```
let grades = [5,5,6,7,6,7,9,10,8,6];

let finalSpread = grades.reduce((spread, grade) => {
  let count = spread[grade] || 0;
  spread[grade] = ++count;
  return spread;
}, {});
```

Seeing as you want a final value that's essentially a map of key-values, I'd recommend `finalSpread` being an object like above.

---

---

**Update:**

If it's *imperative* that it be an array  for whatever reason you could:

a. Add `finalSpread = Object.entries(finalSpread)` at the end *(note: each grade will actually be a string)*

b. Just refactor the function in reduce to check if they array of [grade, count] already exists and either add it or increment it.

c. use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead of an array as the reduce accumulator (if you need the grades to also be numbers - Map allows non-string keys) - then cast it to an array, i.e:

```
let finalSpread = grades.reduce((spread, grade) => {
  let count = spread.get(grade) || 0;
  spread.set(grade, ++count);
  return spread;
}, new Map());
finalSpread = Array.from(finalSpread);
```

*(note: `map` and `Array.from()` have limited browser support.)*

Comment: Actually using `Map` as starting value as accumulator is brilliant. It solves loads of problems.

Answer (score 3):

```
var arr = [];
Object.keys(grades).forEach((key) => {
    var newObj = {};
    newObj[key] = grades[key];
    arr.push(newObj);
});
```

**Using ES6 it could be shorter:**

```
var arr = [];
Object.keys(grades).forEach((key) => {
    arr.push({[key]: grades[key});
});
```

Comment: Gets the keys but not the values for corresponding keys.

Comment: o[key] is the value, I changed it to grades[key[ to make it more clear

Answer (score 3):

You could map the keys with the values. The order does not reflect the order of insertation of the object.

```js
var object = { 5: 1, 6: 3, 2: 4 },
    result = Object
        .keys(object)
        .map(k => ({ [k]: object[k] }));
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: And I was wondering why I cant map over object for an hour forgetting you can map over arrays and not the object. Thanks this is quite concise solution, may I ask how would you go about sorting final array by key value ?

Comment: which order do you need?

Comment: Either descending or ascending both are fine.

Comment: the order is actually ascending, because objects keys which are integers, are sorted by default (in actual javascript).

Answer (score 0):

You may also try:

```
let arrayOfObj = [];
let extractPairs = (jsonObj) => {
for(let item in jsonObj) {
    console.log(item);
    arrayOfObj.push({item: jsonObj[item]})
}
console.log(arrayOfObj);
}
```